# Making field value available in template page-title.html.twig

Tags: theming

My page content type contains the field field_subheading. How can I make this field available in the template page-title.html.twig?
Below code doesn't work, probably because $variables['node'] isn't set. Also, I don't know, if it's correkt to retrieve the field value by `$variables['node']->field_subheading->value;`. Thanks!

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_preprocess_page_title().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
    $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
    if ($node && $node->bundle() == 'page') {
        if (isset($variables['node'])) {
            $variables['subheading'] = $variables['node']->field_subheading->value;
        }
    }
}
```

kk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
  if ($node && $node->bundle() == 'page') {
      $variables['subheading'] = $node->field_subheading->value;
  }
}
```

And in your twig file use {{ subheading }}